# Hive timestamp ISO to UTC conversion

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive

I have strings with ISO 8601 timestamps like `2016-03-07T10:02:37.820+01:00` and I would like to convert them to UTC time. The built-in `to_utc_timestamp` (AFAIK) only takes time zone names (e.g. PST, CET) and not the offsets. At least I tried and failed. Is there an elegant way to achieve this in Hive?

Comment: It's easy to split the thing into `2016-03-07T10:02:37` on one hand and `+1` on the other. So you can get a `unix_timestamp(concat('2016-03-07T10:02:37',' UTC'),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss z')` -- note the fake UTC timezone -- then substract 3600x1 because you've got a +1h offset. Then `from_unixtime(...)`

Comment: Ah, it's more tricky with India because they've got this 1/2h extra offset...

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you can write a Hive UDF for time format conversion.

Another way is, convert ISO timestamps to seconds using `unix_timestamp` and then use `to_utc_timestamp`

```
 TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T.date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") * 1000, '<timezone>')
```

Comment: And I do not have time zone names, I have offsets, so that won't help me. A UDF would work but surely I'm not the first to request this...

Comment: Java [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) defines the lowercase letter `h` to represent `Hour in am/pm (1-12)`. For use with the standard ISO8601 format the double uppercase letter "HH" should be used, which represents `Hour in day (0-23)`.
Moreover, there are numerous ways to represent the timezone offset. See the javadoc website for examples.