# Hive query converting MST timestamps to UTC before serving query results based on where clause

Tags: hive, hql, tableau-api

I have been working on a tableau report which pulls and displays statistics for a group of people. These statistics are collected and organized by a range of parameters, one of them being a timestamp.

I've been battling an issue with my hive query pulling more data than it should be. For example

```
select *

from table1 pre

where date(pre.`timestamp`) between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'
```

This query is pulling a row with a MST timestamp of 2019-10-31 5:19pm, which is the UTC equivalent of 2019-11-01 12:19am

I have spent a few hours researching possible ways around this, our server is configured to MST, I saw a few resources where people suggested converting to a string instead of pulling a timestamp, but this would be massively inconvenient and cause a lot of trouble with the report we're running. I have also tried to specify a timezone in my query before running it with

```
set timezone=MST;
```

but I am running out of ideas. Has anybody else encountered this or an issue similar to this before?

Comment: Have you tried converting either side of your predicate using `from_utc_timestamp`/`to_utc_timestamp`? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: Check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935981/hive-timestamp-iso-to-utc-conversion?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. I tried using that from_utc_timestamp but was having issues. eventually I just found a way to pull the column with the timestamp in unix time, subtracting the seconds for the time difference, and I'm filtering that with a parameter in tableau after converting it from a string to date.

```
,TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(pre.`timestamp`) - 25200))
```